# Unable to install any release version of Meteor on Win 10

Tags: meteor

I've been using 1.1 on Win 10. When 1.2 came out, I tried upgrading but it actually falled back to 0.3. According to sashko a reinstall was necessary, which solved the problem for some. However, nothing happened when I uninstalled and rerun the installer. No files were actually modified. Deleting the %localappdata%/.meteor folder didn't help either. As the installer would no longer put anything there.

The farthest I could get is to get a dev build with a git clone, but I'd like to use a release version either 1.1 or 1.2. Otherwise I'm not able to update my project with a checkout meteor build.

Wrote a bunch of comments on other threads but none of the suggestions helped thus far, so I thought this deserves a new separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to clean the registry of meteor entries.
Credit goes to avalanche1 at: https://forums.meteor.com/t/windows-install-uninstall-hell/2375/7